# Meaning of “…, forbears of one kind and another,…”

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

I just started reading the book "H is for Hawk". The first page has a review that says:

> This beautiful book is at once heartfelt and clever in the way it mixes elegy with celebration: elegy of a father lost, celebration of a hawk found- and in the finding also a celebration of countryside, **forbears** of one kind and another, life-in-death. At a time of very distinguished writing about the relationship between human kind and the environment, it is immediately pre-eminent. – Andrew Motion
>   ([source](https://www.bookdepository.com/H-is-for-Hawk-Birds-Bees-Helen-Macdonald/9781784871109))

*Forbear* means probably ancestors here. What is the implied meaning, I can't understand.

Comment: I am as puzzled as you are. It is a cryptic comment.  Presumably it means ancestors (hence the  'death' reference?). I think you will have to read the book to find out.

Comment: That's a legitimately confusing sentence. I have a hard time parsing it myself.

Comment: If indeed *forbears* means ancestors it is misspelled--should be *forebears.* *Forbear* is a verb meaning *refrain.*

Answer (score 2):

I think the last part of the sentence, from "a celebration" is a complex noun phrase. The book "mixes elegy with celebration", specifically:

1. elegy of a father lost
2. celebration of a hawk found
3. in the finding (of the hawk) celebration of...

   - countryside
   - forbears (i.e. ancestors) of one kind and another
   - life-in-death

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is a slightly non-standard usage of *forbear* to mean not "refrain from", but rather as a noun "ancestor" ([cite](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/forebear)). So the last part of the sentence means:

> and in the finding... [of] **ancestors** of one kind and another, life-in-death.